# Power outage on circuit

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting

Some of the details of this question are a little hazy so please bear with me.

I moved into a townhouse in February. I had a small toaster oven plugged into an outlet but then its stopped working. I believe I reset the breaker (I think it was anyway) and had power again. There are 2 different circuits on panel that say kitchen. I do not believe there is a gfci on either kitchen circuit...only for outside and bathroom receptacles

The power went out again and I figured it could have been due to stab loading due to intermittent power. I replaced all receptacles and wrapped wires around screws. I used to be electrical assistant so I know my receptacles are wired correctly. The power worked again for about a week or 2 then went out again. I also replaced breaker as I was not getting power on the breaker with it on using a voltage sniffer. I also tightened all neutrals in the panel. Still have no power...any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: Is this a rental? If so, you might be obliged to not be messing with the electricity. (And your landlord has an obligation to fix things that go wrong.)

Comment: What make and model is the breaker panel?

Comment: No I own the property. And I dont know the exact model of the panel, but the words "square D load center" come to mind? I know its definitely square D

Comment: Been a while, but have you started chasing outlets between the panel and your faulty one? If the faulty ones were backstabbed, then ones toward the panel probably were as well, which could be the root of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...unfortunately none of the receptacles work. I know where the end of the circuit is, but that's it